# How to pass newline character to textInput in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny app that allows the user to interactively generate a graph. I want them to be able to input axis titles, which may need multiple lines. My approach was to simply use textInput, but R Shiny converts '\n' to '\\n' which is then unusable for the plot titles.

For example, using this app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('text', 'Enter some text:'),
  verbatimTextOutput('print')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$print <- renderPrint(input$text)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

produces this output:

[image]

One workaround I came up with was to input e.g. 'Top line_n_Bottom line' and then add `newtext <- reactive(gsub('_n_', '\n', input$text))` to convert these to newlines. This works, but I think it's a bit clunky. I don't love the idea of making anybody who uses the app enter a weird fake character to format their axis titles properly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try using `textAreaInput()`, I've used it previously and it is able to receive line breaks, but I believe it's up to you to convert line breaks into the proper text you require (e.g., `\n` for ggplot, `<br>` for html, and so on)